# Hook on entering org latex fragment

Tags: org-mode, latex

Hi is there a hook that gets triggered upon entering a LaTeX fragment in org? I'm trying to do

```
(add-hook <enter-org-latex-hook> 'org-cdlatex-mode)
```

but can't seem to find the correct hook to attach to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of any such hook. But you can add one.
The following Elisp code shows how you can use `cursor-sensor-mode` and the `cursor-sensor-functions` text property to call hook functions when the formula overlays are entered or left.

The hook where you can link in is `org+-formula-cursor-sensor-functions`.
Switching on and off `cdlatex-mode` is demonstrated at the end of the code.

```el
(require 'org)
(require 'org-element)
(defvar org+-formula-cursor-sensor-functions nil
  "Functions called when cursor enters or leaves LaTeX preview overlays.
They are called with three arguments WINDOW, POSITION, and ACTION.
ACTION can be 'entered or 'left.
See text property `cursor-sensor-functions' in (info \"(elisp)Special Properties\").")

(defun org+-formula-cursor-sensor-fun (window pos action)
  "Just run hooks in `org+-formula-cursor-sensor-functions'.
Run each of these functions with args WINDOW, POS, and ACTION."
  (run-hook-with-args 'org+-formula-cursor-sensor-functions window pos action))

(defun org+-formula-cursor-sensor (fun beg end &rest args)
  "Add the cursor-sensor-functions property to the overlay between BEG and END.
This is an around advice for `org--format-latex-make-overlay' as FUN.
FUN is called with BEG, END, and the members of ARGS.
It is assumed that FUN returns the display property of the overlay."
  (let* ((ret (apply fun beg end args))
     (ov (cl-loop for ov being the overlays from beg to end
              if (eq (overlay-get ov 'display) ret)
              return ov)))
    (overlay-put ov 'cursor-sensor-functions (list #'org+-formula-cursor-sensor-fun))
    ret))

(advice-add 'org--format-latex-make-overlay :around #'org+-formula-cursor-sensor)

(defun org+-cdlatex-when-formula-entered (window _pos action)
  "Depending on ACTION switch cdlatex on or off in the buffer of WINDOW.
Switch it on if ACTION is 'entered and off otherwise."
  (with-current-buffer (window-buffer window)
    (if (eq action 'entered)
    (cdlatex-mode)
      (cdlatex-mode -1))))

(defun org+-auto-cdlatex ()
  "Automatically switch cdlatex on or off when formula overlays are entered or left."
  (cursor-sensor-mode)
  (add-hook 'org+-formula-cursor-sensor-functions #'org+-cdlatex-when-formula-entered))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'org+-auto-cdlatex)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to this question specifically but you may wish to see how the [org-fragtog](https://github.com/io12/org-fragtog.git) package handles movement of point in and out of LaTeX fragments.